# Knockout JS select box issue

Tags: knockout.js, mootools, knockout-3.0

I am using knockout 3.4.0 for my project along with MooTools . I need to store an information of fields. One of the information is a select box which was loaded through KO .

```
<select data-bind="options: agencyContacts,optionsText: 'name',optionsValue:'id' , optionsCaption: 'Please select...',value:agencyContactSelected">
```

Information is saved in the database. While the same information is loaded from DB i need to have the select box automatically selected with the corresponding DB entry .My ViewModel is below.

```
var vm={};
var Information = {

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    /**
     * Method: initialize
     *
     * Parameters:
     *  options (object) - the options object
     */
    initialize: function(options) {

        var self = this;
        self.draw();
    },
     draw: function() {
        vm.agencyContactViewModel.agencyContactSelected(<ID>);
     }
}

var agencyContactViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.agencyId = ko.observable();
    self.agencyContacts = ko.observableArray();
    self.agencyContactSelected = ko.observable();
    self.agencyContactSelected.subscribe(function(newAgencyContactSelected) {
            alert(newAgencyContactSelected);
    });

    self.agencyId.subscribe(function(newAgencyId) {
        self.agencyContacts.removeAll();
        self.address();
        var submitObj = {
            'contactId': newAgencyId
        };
        var myRequest = new ReqJSON({
            'url': '/gateway?file=contacts.views&method=getContactRefs',
            onSuccess: function(responseJSON) {
                if (responseJSON.length > 0) {
                    var length = responseJSON.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        self.agencyContacts.push(responseJSON[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).send(JSON.encode(submitObj));
    });
}

 myInformation = new Information();

 window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    vm.agencyContactViewModel = new agencyContactViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm.agencyContactViewModel, document.getElementById('agency_contact_wrapper'));
});
```

While i have set the correct ID for the select box , the corresponding subscribe function of the 'agencyContactSelected' observable is called twice ,first having the ID from the DB and the second time having undefined value. Due to this undefined value , the select box is not being set. What could be the reason?

PS: If i remove 'value:agencyContactSelected' from HTML , the subscribe is called correctly ie , once with DB value.

Comment: When the `agencyId` changes, you clear all `agencyContacts`. This will re-evaluate the `options` binding, removing all the `option`s inside it. There is still a selected ID, but knockout won't be able to find the corresponding value. This will result in setting an undefined value. Later, when (asynchronously) the items re-appear, it will have lost its selection state and not be able to retrieve it.

Comment: @user3297291 Even if i remove agencyId subscribe function in which the agencyContacts are updated , the agencyContactSelected subscribe function is still called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I see several surprising elements in your question:

1. Why do you use `optionsValue`? It does not seem useful here
2. In your `draw` function, you call `agencyContactViewModel.agencyContactSelected`, but `agencyContactViewModel` is a function. Using the same name for both the function and the property of your viewmodel is quite tricky and you should avoid it
3. I don't see the definition of your `vm` variable

Comment: 1) I was under the impression that whatever specified in the optionsValue will be set in the agencyContactSelected ( value attribute )
2) I missed that 
3) edited

Comment: Any improvement? Also, as `Information` is not a function, I am very curious to know what this code does: `myInformation = new Information();`

Comment: No improvement still.Information is MooTools based class. While calling new Information() ,it will call the initialize method in the Information class.